# Textbox AutoComplete ( call handler in .ascx page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, dotnetnuke-module

I want to call Generic Handler in `.ascx` page for textbox autocomplete in dotnetnuke module.

I use this code but not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("[id*=txtSearch]").autocomplete({ source: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Search_CS.ashx" ) %>' });
    });      
</script>
```

Comment: What do mean by not working? check your console log.

Comment: when i use this code in .aspx, works properly but when i use in .ascx page not working.

Comment: Please, read my upper comment about *console log* and check it, and add it in your question if there any!

Comment: i an new in dotnetnuke module development. where is console log?

Comment: It doesn't relate with it, [check in your browser](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

Comment: thanks a lot. i run console log and found resolveurl is wrong. i changed it and it works properly.

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error in console. probably your autocomplete *URL* goes wrong when you call Generic Handler, and this doesn't relate with dotnetnuke.

If you're new to javascript/Jquery please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/4753489), for checking console log.